# date sorting doesn't work in the datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatables

I had a problem with the date sort, It didn't include the month while sorting, and sorted only by the day. 
I solved it by adding the next code:

```
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "datetime-pre": function ( a ) {
        var ukDatea = a.split('/');
        return (ukDatea[2] + ukDatea[1] + ukDatea[0]) * 1;
    },

    "datetime-asc": function ( a, b ) {
        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
    },

    "datetime-desc": function ( a, b ) {
        return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
    }
    } );
    var dt = $('#wires').DataTable({
       "aoColumns": [
           null,
           null,
           { "sType": "datetime" },
           { "sType": "datetime" },
           null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null
       ],
```

But now the column sorting (part of the datatable header) is not working only of one of the columns which include date.
Any advice/solutions?

Comment: Can you provide us a full snippet with also your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

What is the date format you're trying to sort?

I made functions to sort pt-BR date (dd/MM/yyyy) and datetime (dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss). I had to convert the dates to integers in order to compare properly. For example: the date "25/03/2016" become the integer 20160325.

Take a look:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "br_datetime-asc": function (a, b) {
        var x, y;
        if (jQuery.trim(a) !== '') {
            var deDatea = jQuery.trim(a).split(' ');
            var deTimea = deDatea[1].split(':');
            var deDatea2 = deDatea[0].split('/');
            if (typeof deTimea[2] !== 'undefined') {
                x = (deDatea2[2] + deDatea2[1] + deDatea2[0] + deTimea[0] + deTimea[1] + deTimea[2]) * 1;
            } else {
                x = (deDatea2[2] + deDatea2[1] + deDatea2[0] + deTimea[0] + deTimea[1]) * 1;
            }
        } else {
            x = Infinity; // = l'an 1000 ...
        }

        if (jQuery.trim(b) !== '') {
            var deDateb = jQuery.trim(b).split(' ');
            var deTimeb = deDateb[1].split(':');
            deDateb = deDateb[0].split('/');
            if (typeof deTimeb[2] !== 'undefined') {
                y = (deDateb[2] + deDateb[1] + deDateb[0] + deTimeb[0] + deTimeb[1] + deTimeb[2]) * 1;
            } else {
                y = (deDateb[2] + deDateb[1] + deDateb[0] + deTimeb[0] + deTimeb[1]) * 1;
            }
        } else {
            y = Infinity;
        }
        var z = ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
        return z;
    },

    "br_datetime-desc": function (a, b) {
        var x, y;
        if (jQuery.trim(a) !== '') {
            var deDatea = jQuery.trim(a).split(' ');
            var deTimea = deDatea[1].split(':');
            var deDatea2 = deDatea[0].split('/');
            if (typeof deTimea[2] !== 'undefined') {
                x = (deDatea2[2] + deDatea2[1] + deDatea2[0] + deTimea[0] + deTimea[1] + deTimea[2]) * 1;
            } else {
                x = (deDatea2[2] + deDatea2[1] + deDatea2[0] + deTimea[0] + deTimea[1]) * 1;
            }
        } else {
            x = Infinity;
        }

        if (jQuery.trim(b) !== '') {
            var deDateb = jQuery.trim(b).split(' ');
            var deTimeb = deDateb[1].split(':');
            deDateb = deDateb[0].split('/');
            if (typeof deTimeb[2] !== 'undefined') {
                y = (deDateb[2] + deDateb[1] + deDateb[0] + deTimeb[0] + deTimeb[1] + deTimeb[2]) * 1;
            } else {
                y = (deDateb[2] + deDateb[1] + deDateb[0] + deTimeb[0] + deTimeb[1]) * 1;
            }
        } else {
            y = Infinity;
        }
        var z = ((x < y) ? 1 : ((x > y) ? -1 : 0));
        return z;
    },

    "br_date-asc": function (a, b) {
        var x, y;
        if (jQuery.trim(a) !== '') {
            var deDatea = jQuery.trim(a).split('/');
            x = (deDatea[2] + deDatea[1] + deDatea[0]) * 1;
        } else {
            x = Infinity; // = l'an 1000 ...
        }

        if (jQuery.trim(b) !== '') {
            var deDateb = jQuery.trim(b).split('/');
            y = (deDateb[2] + deDateb[1] + deDateb[0]) * 1;
        } else {
            y = Infinity;
        }
        var z = ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
        return z;
    },

    "br_date-desc": function (a, b) {
        var x, y;
        if (jQuery.trim(a) !== '') {
            var deDatea = jQuery.trim(a).split('/');
            x = (deDatea[2] + deDatea[1] + deDatea[0]) * 1;
        } else {
            x = Infinity;
        }

        if (jQuery.trim(b) !== '') {
            var deDateb = jQuery.trim(b).split('/');
            y = (deDateb[2] + deDateb[1] + deDateb[0]) * 1;
        } else {
            y = Infinity;
        }
        var z = ((x < y) ? 1 : ((x > y) ? -1 : 0));
        return z;
    }
});
```

Edit:
And in the columnDefs you should set br_datetime or br_date. Or maybe use the type-detection plugin (https://datatables.net/plug-ins/type-detection/) with custom functions:

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.aTypes.unshift(
    function (sData) {
        if (sData !== null && typeof sData !== 'string') {
            sData = sData.toString();
        }
        if (sData !== null && sData.match(/^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(0[1-9]|1[012])\/(19|20|21)\d\d$/)) {
            return 'br_date';
        }
        else if (sData !== null && sData.match(/^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(0[1-9]|1[012])\/(19|20|21)\d\d [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}(:[0-9]{2})?$/)) {
            return 'br_datetime';
        }
        return null;
    }
);
```